# Python tree data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

I have written this code for calculating number of nodes in a tree but I am not getting the RIGHT answer.

The count is not getting added every time when it is returning back. I don't know why. The answer I am getting is `1+1=2`.
only once the count is coming into the account.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    def size(a):
       count1 = 0
       count2 = 0
    if not a:
        return 0
    else:
       size(a.left)
       count1 +=1
       size(a.right)
       count2 +=1
   return count1+count2

   root1 = Node(1)
   root2 = Node(1)
   root1.left = Node(2)
   root1.right = Node(3)
   root1.left.left = Node(4)
   root1.left.right = Node(5)
   root1.left.right.left=Node(6)

   p=size(root1)
   print(p)
```

Comment: You're calling `size(a.left)` and `size(a.right)`, but you're not storing this result anywhere to be used.

Comment: like Fernando said, you'll need to pass in the count variable to the size method to keep track of the size, alternatively, you could have the Tree class keep a size variable that increments as you add nodes.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: @chatton Hi sir, could please edit the code and paste here. So that it will be very helpful for me.I am new to coding

Comment: Getting the indentation wrong in C or C++ just makes your code hard to read.  Getting it wrong in python *completely changes the meaning*.  The code as shown will return out of a class definition which will provoke a syntax error.

Comment: In particular, is `size` supposed to be a standalone function, or a member function?  (Member would be better).  If it's a member, the argument should be called `self`.

Comment: @MartinBonner Since we just have a `Node` class, it's ok for `size` to be a standalone helper function. Of course, if we also had a full `Tree` class, then it would make sense for `size` to be a method of `Tree`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I'm coming round to the view that standalone is better (because it works with `null`), but the OP needs to fix indentation.

Comment: @MartinBonner I totally agree re: indentation, which is why I mentioned it at the start of my answer, and upvoted the previous comments that mentioned indentation. Sure, we _could_ fix the indentation ourselves, but it's against SO Python community policy to do that, since it's so easy to "edit away" code faults that way, which would count as a conflict with the original author's intentions.

Comment: Yup.  With C++ I would just go ahead and fix it.  With Python you can *easily* fix an error like that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, correct indentation is *vital* in Python.

Apart from the indentation issue, your `size` function actually counts each node twice, but you don't use the return value of the recursive calls, so they don't get added to the count.

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

# Find the size of the tree rooted at `a`
def size(a):
    if not a:
        return 0
    # count is 1 for this node + the sizes of the subtrees
    count = 1 + size(a.left) + size(a.right)
    return count

# Build a tree
root1 = Node(1)
root1.left = Node(2)
root1.right = Node(3)
root1.left.left = Node(4)
root1.left.right = Node(5)
root1.left.right.left=Node(6)

# Print its size
p = size(root1)
print(p)
```

**output**

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def add_node(self, data):
        self.root = self._add_node(data, self.root)
        self.size += 1  # we're about to add a new node, so we have one more element!

    def _add_node(self, data, node):
        node_to_add = Node(data)
        if not node:
            return node_to_add

        if node.data >= node_to_add.data:
            node.left = self._add_node(data, node.left)
        elif node.data < node_to_add.data:
            node.right = self._add_node(data, node.right)

        return node

    def print_tree(self):
        self._print_tree(self.root)

    def _print_tree(self, starting_node):
        if starting_node is None:
            return

        self._print_tree(starting_node.left)
        print starting_node.data,
        self._print_tree(starting_node.right)

    def count_number_nodes(self):
        return self._count_number_of_nodes(self.root)

    def _count_number_of_nodes(self, starting_node):

        num = 1
        if starting_node.left is not None:
            num += self._count_number_of_nodes(starting_node.left)

        if starting_node.right is not None:
            num += self._count_number_of_nodes(starting_node.right)

        return num


tree = Tree()
tree.add_node(10)
tree.add_node(42)
tree.add_node(1)
tree.add_node(-14)
tree.add_node(32)
tree.add_node(12)

print "printing in order traversal of tree (smallest to biggest)"
tree.print_tree()
print
print "size from member variable: " + str(tree.size)
print "size from method call: " + str(tree.count_number_nodes())
```

output

```
printing in order traversal of tree (smallest to biggest)
-14 1 10 12 32 42
size from member variable: 6
size from method call: 6
```

In this example, I included two ways of retrieving the size, one is keeping track of a member variable, the other is calculating the size based on the number of nodes in the tree.

The member variable way is much faster and recommended, as it is a single operation to get the size of the tree. When using the method, it counts **every** node. Which gives it O(n) time complexity vs O(1) of the member variable access.

However, for the size variable to be accurate, you must be consistent in how you add new nodes to the tree, eg if you say tree.root.left = Node(6), this will not increment the size variable, and then it will be inaccurate.

This example is a basic implementation of a BST (binary search tree), a BST has a property which says that a node in the tree must have between 0 and 2 child nodes, the left node must be less than the node, and the right node must be grater than the node. *less* and *greater* than depend on the data type in the node.

I hope this examples helps.